# jar and No Class definition found error

Tags: java, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a java program for sending mail and I import some package that is related to the program. I have downloded package **javax.mail** and **javax.activation** and put it in to the **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext**

I compile my program then it compiles but when I run it throws Exception.
[image]

I am not able to understand why it is throwing exception.

> my code is here.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SendEmail
{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "rs.89.rj@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "manoj1990gupta@yahoo.in";
        try{
      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }}catch(Exception e){}    
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `java` is perhaps not the one you think (I mean JDK **and** JRE installation on the same machine). If `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\java SendMail` works, then you have a JDK and a JRE installation

Comment: Pls print `java.home` system property in your main method to know what is the Java path your program is using? Your jre/lib/ext path may be different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR) package and put it into the classpath, but make sure to include mail.jar and all dependant libraries that you can find into the lib folder.

To set the classpath from the command line :

```
java -cp "mail.jar;lib/*" SendEMail
```

Comment: I was about to upvote before I saw *"otherwise you can put every jar lib you need in the `jre\lib\ext` folder"*.  Bad advice that Sun was advising against for several years before Oracle bought them (yes, that long ago).  Suggesting that to a newbie is the wrong way to go, IMO.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok, I Removed. I added that only because the asker mentioned that procedure .

Comment: *"only because the asker mentioned that procedure"*  I missed that bit!  And yes, my comment was in the spirit of "don't mention it to those who've never heard it" so I rather missed the mark on that one.  :P

Comment: tell me one thing where we exactly put the jar file who i downlod .

Comment: @ManojGupta in the directory where you run the program, in your case I think : F:\workspace\Java\connectivity

Comment: yes i have puted in to the same location but also it is not working.@aleroot

Comment: @ManojGupta Extract the zip you've downloaded in that directory and run the program as in my example ...